# Помогите доработать функцию,которая определяет последовательные числа в массиве(если такие имеются),а если нет таких,то возвращает само число

Tags: python

Имею число в строковом виде. Надо определить состоит ли это число из последовательных чисел.Если это так,то функция выводит первое последовательное порядковое число,а если нет,то возвращает само число.Писала код с помощью срезов. У меня получилось вот что:

```py
def find(s):
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        if int(s[i:i+i])- int(s[:i])==1:
            return int(s[:i])
    return int(s)
```

Для строк `s="17181920"`, `s="1234567891011"`, `s="7263723"` функция работает, выводит `17`, `1` и `7263723`, а вот для `s="91011"` и `s="99100"` функция вместо `9` и `99` возвращает `91011` и `99100`. Ещё подумала, переделала:\

```py
def find(s):
   list1=[]
   list2=[]
   for i in range(1,len(s)):
       list1.append(s[:i])
       list2.append(s[1:i+1])
       for i in list1:
           for j in list2:
               if int(j)-int(i)==1:
                   return int(i)
  return int(s)
```

В этом случае функция для `s="91011"` выводит `9`, а для `s="17181920"` уже возвращает `17181920` вместо ожидаемого `17`. Я пробовала найти все комбинации:

```py
res=[s[i:j]for i in range(len(s))for j in range(i+1,len(s)+1)]
```

и с помощью `from itertools import combinations` выбрать подходящую:

```
tot=[pair for pair in combinations(res,2)if int(pair[1])-int(pair[0])==1]
```

Все напрасно! Я новичек, буду благодарна любой подсказке! Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Условие задачи неоднозначное если будет "101112101113"  какое число получится 1,10,101112

Comment: @Oopss В моём понимании 101112, но тут тоже не очень уловил...

Comment: @Amgarak здесь есть последовательности 1,2; 10,11,12; 101112, 101113 какое выбрать в задании не сказано.

Comment: Разумно искать последовательность с самым малым первым числом.

Comment: Последовательность в данной задаче одна: непрерывная последовательность порядковых чисел. Если последовательность прерывается, например: "2349101112" в этом случае функция должна возвратить само это число. Суть в том,что последовательность порядковых чисел либо есть, либо нет . Функция возвращает либо первое число последовательности порядковых чисел либо само это число.                      .

Answer (score 0):

Не рискну сказать, что работает верно, так как возможно не очень уловил суть задачи, но для предоставленных данных ожидаемый вывод:

```
def find(s):
    length = len(s)
    
    for i in range(1, length):
        num = int(s[:i])
        temp = i
        while temp < length and int(s[temp:temp + len(str(num + 1))]) == num + 1:
            temp += len(str(num + 1))
            num += 1
        
        if temp == length:
            return int(s[:i])

    return int(s)

# Примеры использования
print(find("17181920"))  # Вывод: 17
print(find("1234567891011"))  # Вывод: 1
print(find("7263723"))  # Вывод: 7263723
print(find("91011"))  # Вывод: 9
print(find("99100"))  # Вывод: 99
```